# How to receive entire data comming from server in python socket

Tags: python, socket.io

I am Using Python socket lib, i want to receive the entire data coming from server i have tried using loops but it stucking after reading the data.

```py
    def readReply(self):
        recv_data = b''
        while True:
            data = self.client_socket.recv(1024)
            if data:
                recv_data += data
            else:
                break
        return recv_data
```

Comment: You're collecting the data in a variable named `recv_data`, but then you return a different variable named `buffer`.

Comment: sorry that's a typo error same

Comment: What does "but it stucking after reading the data" mean?

Comment: data condition is never getting false then what will happen

Comment: @Jocefyneroot is that really the problem? Aren't you stuck on `self.client_socket.recv(1024)`? If the socket is in blocking mode and no data is received, this function will block the thread forever. Setting a timeout before receiving any data and using a `try-except` block to catch the timeout exception should be the way to go.

Comment: Though, I can only guess this might be the problem as you didn't provided any other script about how you're creating the socket, and which options you're setting on it before calling `readReply(self)`.

Comment: i have already tried  ```time.sleep()```  and  ```try-except```  but it is not working

Comment: No. `time.sleep()` will also freeze the thread. You must set the socket timeout like this: `self.client_socket.settimeout(0.1)`. Check the python socket documentations for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I mean about the timeout is this:

```
def readReply(self):
    recv_data = b''

    # This will block the socket for 0.1s
    #
    # If you have a poor internet connection, you
    # may need to increase this value to a higher
    # one.
    self.client_socket.settimeout(0.1)
    while True:
        try:
            data = self.client_socket.recv(1024)
        except:
            break
        else:
            recv_data += data

    return recv_data
```

Once the timeout is reached, the *while-loop* will break. Note: if you don't want to freeze the main thread while waiting for the incoming data (in case you're using a GUI), you should use *multithreading*.